# MobileFirstPlatform 8.0 Push Configuration Error

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud

Created MFP CF app in Bluemix.  Push notification was also working fine with GCM.  Today saw a messages that there is an update for MFP in the Bluemix dashboard and clicked "Recreate" button.  Server was recreated and all my apps and adapters were gone.  Then from my development environment pushed the app and adapters and went to console to configure push notification and add the GCM details.  Found an error at the top and now I don't see the text box to add the "Server API Key" and "Sender ID"

[image: Push Configuration Error Message]

Looks like the new update got this issue.  Is there a way to fix it or backout and go to the previous version?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is work to assure that such events will not happen, however please note this very important notice about the Mobile Foundation Bluemix service, with the Developer plan:

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/bluemix/using-mobile-foundation/

> **Note:** the Developer plan does not offer a persistent database, as such be sure to backup your configuration as explained in the Troubleshooting section.

Such data loss **may occur**.

For now you will need to reconfigure your GCM credentials in the console.

Comment: The problem is not reconfiguring...the problem is the **text boxes** are missing to add my GCM configuration.  Previously also when the servers were restarted I would loose everything, but this time the **textbox** to enter the values are missing.  How do I configure GCM?

Comment: Did you try clicking the delete button? delete the server instance and recreate it?

Comment: Thanks Idan.  Deleting and recreating resolved the issue.  I guess the update Server code corrupted some configuration.  All working now.